# Compiler Error E2451 Undefined Symbol 'EXEC' in function main()

Tags: sql, c, oracle

Here is a sample of a program that I got from the website: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/server.815/a68022/sql.htm:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

/* declare host variables */ 
char userid[12] = "SCOTT/TIGER";
char emp_name[10];
int emp_number;
int dept_number; 
char temp[32];
void sql_error();

/* include the SQL Communications Area */ 
//#include <sqlca.h> 

main() 
{ emp_number = 7499;
/* handle errors */ 
EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR do sql_error("Oracle error");

/* connect to Oracle */ 
EXEC SQL CONNECT :userid; 
printf("Connected.\n"); 

/* declare a cursor */ 
EXEC SQL DECLARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT ename 
FROM emp 
WHERE deptno = :dept_number;
```

Whenever the compiler gets to the `EXEC` statement a compile error occurs:

> E2451 SQL.CPP 17: Undefined symbol 'EXEC' in function main()

I am using Borland c++ VER 5.5.1 and SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Do you think you could fix the code markup a bit? (Paste your code, highlight it and press the {} button on the editor).

Answer (score 2):

Those SQL statements aren't valid C code, and need to go through an additional preprocessor before compilation, which knows how to transform the raw SQL statements into C.

Start at the earlier chapters from your link, particularly [Chapter 1](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/server.815/a68022/intro.htm), *What Is an Oracle Precompiler?*.

Comment: I apologize for this post, please vote to help me lift the ban.

Comment: @StevenAndler sorry I don't understand. what do you mean by _lift the ban_?

Comment: @StevenAndler if you mean that you don't have upvote privileges, I can't help with that with a single up-vote. If you find any of the answers acceptable, then you **can** accept an answer to your questions by clicking the checkmark on the left of an answer, under the vote arrows. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/186209

Answer (score 0):

The code on that page **is not C++**.

It's a special dialect for use with the [Pro*C/C++ Precompiler](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/server.815/a68022/intro.htm). (Link copied from @pb2q.)